# PHP exec function: how to run HBPLUS through PHP

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I've got a problem related to PHP exec() function and the output of HBPLUS program. When I try to run the following command "**./hbplus pPDBfile.pdb**" from a Linux Terminal, all works perfectly (no extension for ./hbplus is required): it creates a **multiple lines** output in the terminal and a **pPDBfile.hb2** file. That's what I need. Instead, when I try to launch it from PHP, it gives me a "**Segmentation fault**" error.

```
$hbplus = "hbplus p1a6z.pdb"; //p1a6z.pdb is the pdb I have -> p in front is required.
exec($hbplus); //Segmentation fault.
```

Moreover, I tried to replace the exec() function with system(), shell_exec() and passthru() functions. Also, I tried to add

```
2>&1
```

in order to have:

```
$hbplus = "hbplus p1a6z.pdb 2&>1";
```

The result is the same.

Do you have any suggestions? Do you think the problem is related to the multiple lines output I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried defining absolute paths for both the application and the .pdb file?

Comment: Both pdb file and hblus are in the same directory.

Comment: If you look at your command line call (which works), you have `./` in front of the application. That's a path (the same folder). Try and add absolute paths on both and see if it works.

Comment: No, It does not work if I put the absolute path in both application and pdb file.